# hide bullets list when links are hidden Using Jquery or CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to hide bullets list if the links are hidden  the first and second link are hidden by backend code C# I am trying to hide the bullets if thire are no links

```
<div class="lower lts-orange">
     <ul id="interact">
           <li>
           </li>
           <li>
           </li>
           <li><a id="print">Print</a></li>
           <li><a id="dnn_ctr932_View_lb_like" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr932$View$lb_like','')">Liked</a></li>
           <li><a href="#dnn_notePan">Note</a></li>
           <li><a href="#dnn_commentsPan">Comment</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "hidden" ? set display to none? or visibility: hidden?

Comment: why don't you just hide the complete `<li>` tag in your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#interact li').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('a').length === 0;
}).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhmhN/